# "Go to symbol in file" not working for PHP

Tags: windows-10, php, visual-studio-code, symbols

For some reason, the "Go to symbol in file..." dialog for PHP only has an empty list. That dialog works fine for other languages, like JavaScript or TypeScript, but not PHP. I've set the PHP executable path but it didn't make a difference.

Any idea what to do to make it work?

Comment: Don't you think you should better ask it on [SO]?

Comment: SuperUser is for questions about software, which is why I asked here.

Comment: I got that, but 1) SO allows questions relating to developer tools, which VS Code certainly is, 2) SO has much bigger community, so you would have a higher chance of getting an answer quicker. :)

Comment: That's true, I've posted my question there too then, thanks for the suggestion.